# Python - create a column to highlight which cells of another column are NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

This seems like it should be really easy but it is beating me.
I need to turn the following:

| year_1 | year_2 |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 25 |
| nan | 30 |
| 34 | nan |
| nan | nan |

into the following:

| year_1 | year_2 | y1_nan | y2_nan |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 25 | 0 | 0 |
| nan | 30 | 1 | 0 |
| 34 | nan | 0 | 1 |
| nan | nan | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

Try `join` with `isna` and `astype(int)`, and add a suffix of `'_nan'`:

```
>>> df.join(df.isna().astype(int), rsuffix='_nan')
   year_1  year_2  year_1_nan  year_2_nan
0    23.0    25.0           0           0
1     NaN    30.0           1           0
2    34.0     NaN           0           1
3     NaN     NaN           1           1
>>>
```

Comment: That works! However my df has more variables... when I tried to specify only the variables that I want it gave me an error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute'join'